Why does running openvpn fail here?
I am following https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-openvpn to use it on NixOS.
First, install openvpn and openresolv in a nix shell
$ nix-shell -p openvpn openresolv
these 4 paths will be fetched (3.18 MiB download, 18.17 MiB unpacked):
  /nix/store/fzn8w14l8jbmvgdxsf1gc48h64gwj8k8-lzo-2.10
  /nix/store/g96waiv2vcsaq1b05x3mnkq2229y28qs-util-linux-2.38.1-bin
  /nix/store/jr9xkl7vm380ja0ajvfby0xqj4gj91m7-openvpn-2.5.8
  /nix/store/y8b0v1yvkr4h3ir99k2asa8k3n1yp5aj-util-linux-2.38.1-lib
copying path '/nix/store/fzn8w14l8jbmvgdxsf1gc48h64gwj8k8-lzo-2.10' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
copying path '/nix/store/y8b0v1yvkr4h3ir99k2asa8k3n1yp5aj-util-linux-2.38.1-lib' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
copying path '/nix/store/g96waiv2vcsaq1b05x3mnkq2229y28qs-util-linux-2.38.1-bin' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
copying path '/nix/store/jr9xkl7vm380ja0ajvfby0xqj4gj91m7-openvpn-2.5.8' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...

Then, download the DNS update script created by ProtonVPN
$ sudo wget "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ProtonVPN/scripts/master/update-resolv-conf.sh" -O "/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf"
$ sudo chmod +x "/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf"

Finally, connect to a vpn server specified in a downloaded .ovpn file using UDP, but it fails:
$ cd ~/Download/protonvpn/
$ sudo openvpn us-free-203009.protonvpn.udp.ovpn 
2024-07-08 18:30:19 OpenVPN 2.5.8 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Oct 28 2022
2024-07-08 18:30:19 library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.11 19 Sep 2023, LZO 2.10
Enter Auth Username: *********
Enter Auth Password: *********
2024-07-08 18:31:09 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
2024-07-08 18:31:09 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]89.187.180.1:5060
2024-07-08 18:31:09 UDP link local: (not bound)
2024-07-08 18:31:09 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]89.187.180.1:5060

2024-07-08 18:32:09 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
2024-07-08 18:32:09 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
2024-07-08 18:32:09 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
2024-07-08 18:32:14 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
2024-07-08 18:32:14 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]89.187.180.1:4569
2024-07-08 18:32:14 UDP link local: (not bound)
2024-07-08 18:32:14 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]89.187.180.1:4569
2024-07-08 18:33:14 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
2024-07-08 18:33:14 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
2024-07-08 18:33:14 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting

and then I try another .ovpn file using TCP, and it still fails:
$ sudo openvpn us-free-112030.protonvpn.tcp.ovpn 
[sudo] password for t: 
2024-07-08 18:48:12 OpenVPN 2.5.8 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Oct 28 2022
2024-07-08 18:48:12 library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.11 19 Sep 2023, LZO 2.10
Enter Auth Username: ********
Enter Auth Password: ********
2024-07-08 18:48:37 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
2024-07-08 18:48:37 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]143.244.44.171:8443
2024-07-08 18:48:37 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]143.244.44.171:8443 [nonblock]
2024-07-08 18:50:38 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]143.244.44.171:8443 failed: Connection timed out
2024-07-08 18:50:38 SIGUSR1[connection failed(soft),init_instance] received, process restarting
2024-07-08 18:50:43 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
2024-07-08 18:50:43 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]143.244.44.171:443
2024-07-08 18:50:43 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]143.244.44.171:443 [nonblock]
2024-07-08 18:52:43 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]143.244.44.171:443 failed: Connection timed out
2024-07-08 18:52:43 SIGUSR1[connection failed(soft),init_instance] received, process restarting

Why are the failures? What can I do with them?
The DNS update script https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ProtonVPN/scripts/master/update-resolv-conf.sh looks for resolvconf by type -p resolvconf, and on my computer it is here:
$ type -p resolvconf
/nix/store/cqrakc6jcckf9x67km6q5ybfginpf3pv-openresolv-3.12.0/bin/resolvconf

Do the openvpn commands get to use /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf and the above resolvconf file?
